# gulp-tslint return undefined when required

Tags: gulp, tslint

this is my gulpfile:

```
/*jslint maxlen:160*/
 (function (require) {
   "use strict";
   var gulp, tslint;
   gulp   = require('gulp');
   tslint = require('gulp-tslint');
   gulp.task("tslint", function() {
    return gulp.src(["src/**/*.ts"])
               .pipe(tslint())
               .pipe(tslint.reporter("verbose"));
   });
 }(require));
```

when I run `gulp tslint` from command line I get this error:

> [17:26:58] Using gulpfile /var/www/tests/gulp_error/gulpfile.js
>   [17:26:58] Starting 'tslint'... [17:26:58] 'tslint' errored after 6.08
>   ms [17:26:58] TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at Gulp. (/var/www/tests/gulp_error/gulpfile.js:9:36)
>       at module.exports (/var/www/tests/gulp_error/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/var/www/tests/gulp_error/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/var/www/tests/gulp_error/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/var/www/tests/gulp_error/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
>       at /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.12/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
>       at startup (node.js:129:16)
>       at node.js:814:3

what I'm doing wrong here?
Here's a [Github repository](https://github.com/yahyaKacem/gulp_error) with the code.

Comment: In the docs for `gulp-tslint` it doesn't say anything about `.default()`, shouldn't you just use it like : `.pipe(tslint())`

Comment: sorry, my bad, I removed it.

Comment: That was just a test after I checked the source code, it doesn't change anything, I get the same results with it or without it (.default()).